# patch command output `patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line`

Tags: patch

I am attempting to script diff and patch commands. Facing some warning like this if `bzcat` is used

```
# bzcat consolidated.patch.tar.bz2 | patch -d dev -p1 
  patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
  patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
# echo $?
  0
```

It there is no such warnings if patch is performed with decompressed file

```
# tar -xf consolidated.patch.tar.bz2
# patch -d dev -p1 < consolidated.patch
# echo $?
  0
```

I did compare resultant folder but both approach but they are identical

```
# diff -aurN dev1 dev2 > res.diff
# stat res.diff 
  File: res.diff
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the filename, and the fact that it opens with `tar`, your `consolidated.patch.tar.bz2` is a tar archive that has been compressed with bzip2. It's not like a zip archive where a single tool handles both
sticking the files together and compressing them, but the two steps of aggregating the files (`tar`) and compressing the lot (`bzip2`) are distinct. (Except that smart implementations of `tar` know the common compression tools and can execute them automatically.)

So, what you get with `bzcat` is not the file(s) archived within, but the uncompressed tar archive. Even if it only contains one file. No wonder `patch` can't read it.

With GNU tar (at least), you could use the `-O`/`--to-stdout` option to have the file data sent to stdout:

```
tar -xj -f consolidated.patch.tar.bz2 -O | patch
```

(Or, `... -O consolidated.patch` to output only that file, in case it wasn't the only one after all.)

With only a single file, there wouldn't really be need for the `tar` step, and the file could be compressed without using `tar`, just with `bzip2 consolidated.patch`, creating `consolidated.patch.bz2`, which `bzcat` then does work on.